# Why can I not print out dataframe from Excel in R

Tags: r, excel

Trying to print out dataframe that is created after importing Excel file into R using following code:

```
library("readxl")

data <- read_excel("grad programs.xlsx", sheet="Sheet2")

print(data)
```

But instead of getting the Excel file, I get this really long random message:

```
print(data)
function (..., list = character(), package = NULL, lib.loc = NULL, 
verbose = getOption("verbose"), envir = .GlobalEnv, overwrite = TRUE) 
{
fileExt <- function(x) {
    db <- grepl("\\.[^.]+\\.(gz|bz2|xz)$", x)
    ans <- sub(".*\\.", "", x)
    ans[db] <- sub(".*\\.([^.]+\\.)(gz|bz2|xz)$", "\\1\\2", 
        x[db])
    ans
}
my_read_table <- function(...) {
    lcc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE")
    on.exit(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", lcc))
    Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
    read.table(...)
}
stopifnot(is.character(list))
names <- c(as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1L]), list)
if (!is.null(package)) {
    if (!is.character(package)) 
        stop("'package' must be a character vector or NULL")
}
paths <- find.package(package, lib.loc, verbose = verbose)
if (is.null(lib.loc)) 
    paths <- c(path.package(package, TRUE), if (!length(package)) getwd(), 
        paths)
paths <- unique(normalizePath(paths[file.exists(paths)]))
paths <- paths[dir.exists(file.path(paths, "data"))]
dataExts <- tools:::.make_file_exts("data")
if (length(names) == 0L) {
    db <- matrix(character(), nrow = 0L, ncol = 4L)
    for (path in paths) {
        entries <- NULL
        packageName <- if (file_test("-f", file.path(path, 
            "DESCRIPTION"))) 
            basename(path)
        else "."
```

Message is longer than that, but that's the start - any idea why get this message rather than the actual data in the Excel sheet

Comment: I would guess that something went wrong when importing your dataset. What the printout shows is the `data()` function. One of the reasons I would recommend to not call your datasets just `data` as this quite often results in mysterious issues (or errors not popping up). Instead use e.g. `dat`.

Comment: Thanks yep this does seem to be the issue - print(data) is just printing out the data function!

Comment: Did you not get any error/warning messages with the first line of code? Try `read_excel("grad programs.xlsx", sheet="Sheet2")` to print the result of the function without assigning it to an object first.